# Applescript breaking when application name is a variable?

Tags: path, applescript, photoshop

I have a script on a machine that has multiple versions of Photoshop that looks for any open version of Photoshop (in this case CS6) and saves the name as a variable called AppName.

It seems to work fine for checking "If AppName is running" but later on down the script I have "tell application ... " and when I start doing things inside there, I get error 1728.

Example: I have CS6 open and one image open.

```
tell application AppName
    log count documents
    log file path of document 1
end tell
```

That would generate

```
(*1*)
(*Adobe Photoshop CS6 got an error: Can't get path. - -1728*)
```

It works perfectly fine if I just enter "Adobe Photoshop CS6" or "com.adobe.photoshop", but for various reasons I can't do that and need it to remain a variable.

Anyone have any ideas? =/

Answer (score 0):

The argument of `tell application` must be a literal string (a constant) because the terminology is evaluated at compile time.

The only way to evaluate AppleScript terminology beside `tell application` is an `using terms from` block frequently used in event handlers for example

```
using terms from application "Adobe Photoshop CS6"

end using terms from
```

but this requires also a constant as argument. The implementation depends on the context.